# List of variable inside a string

Tags: python, regex, string

Python provides string formatting like

```
s="{a}|{b}.{c}.{a}"
s.format(a=2, b=3, c=4)
```

which outputs

```
'2|3.4.2'
```

I'm looking for a way to get a list of "variables" inside a string.

So in my example

```
list_of_var(s)
```

should outputs

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding you correctly, are you looking for a way to parse values out of a template string that has already been formatted with certain values? Or, are you looking for a way to extract the variable names that are being used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`string.Formatter.parse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse):

```
>>> s = "{a}|{b}.{c}.{a}"
>>> import string
>>> formatter = string.Formatter()
>>> [item[1] for item in formatter.parse(s)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

```
(?<={)\w+(?=})
```

Example usage

```
>>> import re
>>> s="{a}|{b}.{c}.{a}"
>>> re.findall(r'(?<={)\w+(?=})', s)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

**Regex**

- `(?<={)` look behind, asserts the regex is presceded by `{`
- `\w+` matches the variable name
- `(?=})` look ahead asserts the regex if followed by `}`

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is a single alphanumeric character try:

```
>>> s="{a}|{b}.{c}.{a}"
>>> [c for c in s if c.isalnum()]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```